# DoctrineMigrationsBundle 3.0.1: metadata storage is not up to date

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration

I recently got this error when running `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`:

> The metadata storage is not up to date, please run the `sync-metadata-storage` command to fix this issue.

However, running the `sync-metadata-storage` command yields the same error.
What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried doing what Symfony is saying to you (_run the sync-metadata-storage command_)?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/337#issuecomment-645390496) one possible fix is to specify the MySQL server version in the server URL:

```sh
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/test?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11
```

Then, you should be able to run the `bin/console sync-metadata-storage` command.

Read more about this configuration option in the [doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#automatic-platform-version-detection):

> […] you can pass the `serverVersion` option with a vendor specific version string that matches the database server version you are using […]
>
> If you are running a MariaDB database, you should prefix the serverVersion with `mariadb-` (ex: `mariadb-10.2.12`).

Answer (score 0):

**I had to downgrade the `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` to version `"^2.1"`**

Not sure if that applies here, but I had issues with doctrine lately aswell.
I did a `composer update` and ever since then, my project wouldn't run anymore. My issue was based on a new version of the following bundle:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

They restructred the doctrine_migrations.yaml file and I still had the old one. I tried to change the contents to the new 3.0 version but that lead exactly to your error.

Since the bundle comes with the package: `symfony/orm-pack` you first have to unpack the to be able to manually change the version inside your composer.json: `composer unpack symfony/orm-pack`

After unpacking you will see the following line inside your composer.json: `"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "*"`, which I changed to `"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.1"`. Then i ran `composer update` again. You may specify only the migrations bundle if thats all you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Hello so i could fixe my issue just by removing (?versionname=5.7) to the database_url and it worked just fine

Comment: Hey @Madou, did you remove the version from the url or did you add it to the url?
If you removed it: is it possible, that the version simply wasn't the right one?